# Google Analytics API v3 - Unique Users

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to use the Google api for analytics V3, and get the "Users" metric that I see at the Overview page of the Google Analytics Account.

Although there is a User metric [ga:Users] with the same name (and web name) as the one I am looking for, unfortunately the ga:Users metric returns all the users visited the site, while I need the "unique users".

Is there a way to get that metric, or calculate it somehow?

Comment: Users is a count of distinct users. I think it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately ga:Users is the count of *all* users, not distinct.